# IntelliJ Organize the auto-completion list for imports

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am having a strange problem in IntelliJ, which is constantly interrupting my workflow.

I am using Java 1.6, and IntelliJ 13.1 Ultimate.

On using an unimported class for the first time, the IDE selects some random match for the class. Generally an incorrect import is generated. For instance, on a new Class with no imports, I type `List<`. On typing the `<`, I'm getting an import entry for `javax.validation.constraints.AssertFalse.List`.

I have 'Auto Import turned off in 'Settings | Editor | Auto import'.

In 'Code Style | Java | Imports' (which I don't think affects *auto completion* of imports, I have 'Use single class import', 'Insert imports for inner classes' and 'Use fully qualified names in Javadoc' switched on, and class counts to use '*' as 99 and 5 for normal and static imports respectively.

I DO have 'Insert imports on paste' set to 'Ask' in 'Editor | Auto import', which seems to affect the outcome (If I set it to 'None' no auto completion is attempted until I 'Alt-Enter', in which case the correct class is top of the list).

Is there any way to get the 'Ask' to actually ask, instead of just importing?
Is there any way to have the list order the same between the auto-completion import list and the list shown on 'Alt-Enter'?

BTW, I don't recalll ever having an issue like this on Intellij 12 or lower.

Edit - Nope, just re-checked. When I set the 'Insert imports on paste' to None, it just delays when the incorrect import is entered. Now it's on closing the generic, or pressing 'space' (for non-generics).

Comment: My settings are different. I type List and I get a long list of useless completions. I type the < it goes away and types >. I type String, and it tries to complete String for me, I type esc and it stops. List is then highlighted in red, an auto-import popup appears. I hit alt-enter, java.util.List is on top, with 2 other useless options. This is a fast workflow as I only type 'List<String esc alt-enter enter'. I have settings/auto-import/(tick everything & Ask). In code-style/java/imports I have 'use single class', 1000, 1000 for both import *.

Comment: Do you have Settings | Editor | Code Completion | Insert selected variant by typing dot, space etc?. It looks like some autopopup completion item is selected when you type "<" (which is in the "etc" part).

Comment: Yes I did have 'Insert selected...' selected. Is this a new setting? As stated, I never had this issue with IDEA 12 or lower.